# CachedImage not rendering since Expo 50 Upgrade

Tags: react-native, expo

I upgraded my Expo SDK to 50 from 49 and for some reason my CachedImage's aren't showing. Everything was working as expected before, now only the shape of the image shows. If I change it to a normal image, then everything works perfectly. Is there an obvious package that I missed upgrading?

This Works:

```js
<Image
  style={styles.homeImage}
  source={{ uri: item.picture_compressed }}
  onLoad={() => {
    Animated.timing(imageOpacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }}
/>
```

and this only renders the shape given in styles

```js
<CachedImage
  style={styles.homeImage}
  source={{ uri: item.picture_compressed }}
  cacheKey={item.id}
  onLoad={() => {
    Animated.timing(imageOpacity, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }}
/>
```